# process_vm_readv on archlinux and redhat

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, archlinux

I have a question about the process_vm_readv system call. I found that this system call is there for archlinux and redhat. With redhat, I could use this system call as normal user, however I have to be root to use this system call on archlinux. I want to know if there is anyway I could use this API as normal user on archlinux? And why it's different on these two systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to read /proc/pid1/mem and /proc/pid2/mem do you have permission? Next you can run you program with strace. "strace ./you_app" or first start application and next attach to it "strace -p pid_you_app". I guess even simple man example didn't work.Try also "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope".